# Assembly pushf not correct

Tags: gcc, assembly, stack

The GCC compiler as you can see on this page:
https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly

Treats both pushf and pushfd as 0x9C when pushf should be 0x66, 0x9C.
Is there a way to make this compiler not convert pushf to pushfd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pushfw` to get the 16 bit variant.

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/pushfd.htm. They do indeed share the same operand and which gets executed is a product of the environment, not the instruction.

Comment: Not true. In this debugger you can see the difference. http://i.imgur.com/euWhlAq.png

Comment: I stand corrected, although why you would want to save only 16 bits of 32 bit flags is something I find somewhat puzzling.